# how to detect changes to a folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a folder lets call it ComponentsFolder, it has already some components inside it. If some one inserts a new component, when i start the application it should recognize that a new component has been added and it should extract its path and file size and add to the database (sql server 2005). How can i accomplish this ?

I'm using C# in vs2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the file watcher class which can detect changes to a file or directory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Use a Windows Service to monitor the folder non-stop:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984074%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @It seems like it works only when the changes are done to the folder when the application is running. What about when i add the component to folder before i start the application ?

Comment: Add the class to a Windows Service and log additions to the DB :)